# Why an unmanaged thread in mono it freezes due to the garbage collector while using only fixed fields?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, mono, garbage-collection

I wrote a C # code to run an unmanged thread along with others managed threads in Mono. The unmanaged thread is real time because it is created with Xenomai libraries with the use of a wrapper. The unmanaged thread executes a function written in C# (managed code). I saw that the thread is blocked by the GC because of the priority inversion (I supposed) so I tried to use only fixed fields. However, the final result is not chaged.
Naturally I am working on linux and I am using Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.6

Why an unmanaged thread in mono it freezes due to the garbage collector while using only fixed fields?

Thanks!

This is the pseudo-fuction

```
function_thread(){
     fixed(my_fields){
          while(true){
              my_code_use_only_fixed_fields;
          }
     }
}
```

N.B.
The Mono runtime will automatically register all threads that are created from the managed world with the garbage collector. For developers embedding Mono it is important that they register with the runtime any additional thread they create that manipulates managed objects with mono_thread_attach. You can find this concept in this [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/)

P.S. I suppose that the thread is not attached then the garbage collector does not know of its existence. I suppose this because I've not attached the thread.

Comment: Does your unmanaged thread need to receive a return value from the managed function it is calling? If not you might want to consider not calling it directly from the unmanaged side, but rather use the unmanaged thread to signal a different, managed thread to make the invocation (e.g. via wait handles, or similar).

Comment: The managed function is not called by the unmanged thread but it is the thread's function.

Answer (score 1):

In the MS .NET Runtime, unmanaged threads which access the runtime are automatically registered as managed threads. I would be surprised if Mono does this differently.

This behavior is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When an unmanaged thread enters the runtime ... the system checks the thread-local store of that thread to look for an internal managed Thread object. If one is found, the runtime is already aware of this thread. If it cannot find one, however, the runtime builds a new Thread object and installs it in the thread-local store of that thread.

That being said, if it is desired to have a pure GC-free thread, a pure unmanaged thread can be created which interacts with a 'runner' managed thread through standard asynchronous programming patterns, e.g., wait handles, shared memory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While your unmanaged thread is running managed code, it will be affected by the GC just like any other thread. The current Mono (and MS.NET) GC doesn't allow GC to run concurrently with managed code at all (except perhaps finalizers). There's no analysis to figure out if it would be safe to run code concurrently. Note that there are differences based on the GC you're using (and the last time I checked Mono's GCs, they were still very basic - that has been a while ago, though), but to my knowledge, there will *always* be a point where every "user" thread is suspended. This isn't fundamental and could be changed in a custom GC, but it certainly isn't a simple problem, and it has very limited utility. If you want to avoid GC pauses, you must not use managed code.

And I also have to point out that using `fixed` like this will tend to prevent the GC from working correctly - anything that's fixed will be unavailable during heap compaction, which will result in either heap fragmentation or preventing GC from reclaiming any memory in the worst case.

Comment: The thread is not attached then the garbage collector does not know of its existence. How does GC to block the unmanaged thread?

Comment: @G.Puglisi What do you mean, "not attached"? Any time an unmanaged thread calls managed code, it necessarily becomes intertwined with the GC (only for the duration of the managed code execution, of course). And there's no such thing as "just these few lines of managed code" - any allocation necessarily involves managed memory and thus the GC, for example (even seemingly innocent things like manipulating strings or accessing a method/type for the first time). There's no way for managed code to work reliably if that weren't the case. Don't forget that all managed code runs from unmanaged code.

Comment: @LuaanThe Mono runtime will automatically register all threads that are created from the managed world with the garbage collector. For developers embedding Mono it is important that they register with the runtime any additional thread they create that manipulates managed objects with mono_thread_attach. You can find this concept in this [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/)

Comment: @G.Puglisi You might want to add that information into your question, along with the configuration and version of Mono you're using - I suspect those are going to be quite important. Making a minimal working sample of your problem would also be helpful - even without manually attaching the thread there's plenty of cases where your "unmanaged" thread would stop during GC - e.g. as I already noted with the allocations. There may also be other cases where tracking is automatically added or removed as you switch between managed and unmanaged code, but I'm not sure how Mono handles this.